# NodeJS + MySQL login API, session in client

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest

I have API server for login system and using AngularJS for client side.
What method I should use for to create session using AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much idea about client side but you can try these

Create an API in node.js which checks if the session of the user is true or false. if its true return the user object or send false as the session. Use this API is angular.js to validate the session.

Or save the session in the cache and access it from there. When the session expires delete the cache